# Its a question related to finding roots

Tags: group-theory

$a^3-b^3=1$ where $a$ and $b$ belongs to rational numbers. Thus this equation has rational roots. Whether it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$. Just dont know how to prove it.

Comment: The expression $a^3-b^3$ factors as $(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$. But it is not clear whether that is what you are asking. The only rational roots of the equation are $a=1,b=0$ and $a=0,b=-1$ but that is far from obvious.  It is the case $n=3$ of Fermat's Last Theorem. This case was first settled (probably) by Euler.

Comment: k.i got my answer thank you .similarly for a^n-b^n=1 where n is a positive integer and greater than 2 .will it have rational roots other than 1 or 0 or -1

Comment: The general case of FLT was, as you probably know, proved relatively recently. For $n\gt 2$, there are no rational solutions other than the obvious ones.  Going back and forth from the classical "integers" version to the "rationals" version is straightforward.